# Types of dispersion parameter for binomial data

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, overdispersion, beta-binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

For a model with a binomial proportion as response variable, which is fitted with according to a binomial distribution, a dispersion parameter $\phi$ can be calculated, which is equal to the sum of the squared Pearson residuals divided by the residual degrees of freedom.

I was following along with [an example](http://gbi.agrsci.dk/statistics/courses/phd06/material/Day9-overdispersion-QuasiLikelihood/overdispersion-computing.pdf) I found online and found that the $\phi$ computed by hand matches the dispersion parameter that one gets by specifying `family=quasibinomial()` in the `glm` command (rather than `family=binomial()`) and asking R for

`summary(fittedModelName)$dispersion`

For my toy data set, $\phi = 4.904$ in both cases. When I fit the same model with a beta-binomial distribution (using `betabin` in the `aod` package), I get a dispersion parameter estimate which is very different, sc.

```
Overdispersion coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error   z value   Pr(> z)
phi.(Intercept) 1.376e-01  3.145e-02 4.374e+00 6.102e-06
```

I would like to know how the two types of dispersion parameters differ, and whether there is any way they can be related.

These are the parameters I specified for the `betabin` function:

```
betabin(formula = cbind(Rcnt, total - Rcnt) ~ LANG, random = ~1, 
    data = toyDataSet)
```

Comment: @MartijnWeterings as for my toy data set, this will require some forensics on my home computer to see what I was working on 5.5 years ago! The online example, luckily, has been crawled by internet archive [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20101025113040/http://gbi.agrsci.dk/statistics/courses/phd06/material/Day9-overdispersion-QuasiLikelihood/overdispersion-computing.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

### The glm dispersion

**the glm dispersion is an expression based on the normalized residuals.**

So say you have a model `fittedModelName` Then you get the same for

- manual calculation

  ```
  sum( residuals(fittedModelName, "pearson")^2 ) / fittedModelName$df.residual
  ```
- automatic

  ```
  summary(fittedModelName)$dispersion
  ```

note that you can define the quasibinomial model in two ways. You could use:

- scaled from 0 to 1

  ```
  formula = Rcnt/total ~ LANG
  ```
- scaled from 0 to n

  ```
  formula = cbind(Rcnt, total - Rcnt) ~ LANG
  ```

which gives different results for the calculated dispersion

### The beta-binomial regression by aod's betabin

**In the betabin case the reported dispersion is a model parameter**. This is explained in the documentation of the function.

> The function uses the parameterization .... $\varphi = 1 / (a1 + a2 + 1)$ ... and $\varphi$ is the overdispersion parameter.

You can test this also with the code below:

```
library(aod)

#generate data

set.seed(1)
alpha = 1
beta = 1
n = 40
x <- rbeta(1000, alpha, beta)
y <- qbinom(runif(1000), n, x)

#modeling

mb <- betabin(cbind(y,n-y)~1, random=~1, data=as.data.frame(list(y=y)))
```

which shows that the used dispersion is the inverse of the sum $1+\alpha+\beta$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the coefficients of the beta-distribution.

```
#comparison of dispersion

> mb@param[2]   
phi.(Intercept) 
       0.340159 
> 1/(alpha+beta+1)
[1] 0.3333333
```

### References

The documentation is here:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aod/versions/1.3/topics/betabin

but I prefer to get these documentation files by typing the function name into the console `betabin` or `??betabin`